# C# forms pressing multiple keys simultaneously key handler

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

Is there any way to make a function in C# forms where it can handle multiple simultaneous button pressing?

for example:

```
   private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
        if (Keys.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.A) \<-- Function A
        {
            //do something
        }

        if (Keys.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.B) <-- Function B
        {
            //do something
        }

    }
```

`detected: shift shift + A + B and ran function A and function B at the same time.`

I want to trigger function A & B when I press shift+A+B at the same time and I do not want to do

if(keys.shift && keys.A && keys.B)

Is there a way?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. `if Shift && A && B` seems to do exactly what you state as your goal. What's the issue?

Comment: You can add each key to a collection on KeyDown and remove them on KeyUp, so that collection will always tell you what keys are currently depressed.